# Unbound local variable problem in Python

Tags: python, function, exception, bug-tracking, local-variables

I've got a following code snippet:

```
def isolation_level(level):
    def decorator(fn):
        def recur(level, *args, **kwargs):
            if connection.inside_block:
                if connection.isolation_level < level:
                    raise IsolationLevelError(connection)
                else:
                    fn(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                connection.enter_block()
                try:
                    connection.set_isolation_level(level)
                    fn(*args, **kwargs)
                    connection.commit()
                except IsolationLevelError, e:
                    connection.rollback()
                    recur(e.level, *args, **kwargs)
                finally:
                    connection.leave_block()
        def newfn(*args, **kwargs):
            if level is None: # <<<< ERROR MESSAGE HERE, Unbound local variable `level`
                if len(args):
                    if hasattr(args[0], 'isolation_level'):
                        level = args[0].isolation_level
                elif kwargs.has_key('self'):
                    if hasattr(kwargs['self'], 'isolation_level'):
                        level = kwargs.pop('self', 1) 
            if connection.is_dirty():
                connection.commit()
            recur(level, *args, **kwargs)
        return newfn
    return decorator
```

It really doesn't matter what it does, however I post it in its original form, as I was unable to recreate the situation with anything simpler.

The problem is that when I call `isolation_level(1)(some_func)(some, args, here)` I get `Unbound local variable` exception in line 21 (marked on the listing). I don't understand why. I tried recreating the same structure of functions and function calls that wouldn't contain all the implementation details to figure out what is wrong. However I don't get the exception message then. For example the following works:

```
def outer(x=None):
    def outer2(y):
        def inner(x, *args, **kwargs):
            print x
            print y
            print args
            print kwargs
        def inner2(*args, **kwargs):
            if x is None:
                print "I'm confused"
            inner(x, *args, **kwargs)
        return inner2
    return outer2

outer(1)(2)(3, z=4)
```

Prints:

```
1
2
(3,)
{'z': 4}
```

What am I missing??

**EDIT**

Ok, so the problem is that in the first version I actually perform an assignment to the variable. Python detects that and therefore assumes the variable is local.

Comment: The error message can be reproduced in a few lines, and it's easy if one knows what causes it. See http://codepad.org/nI0vCx4L

Comment: @delnan: the shortest code that causes the error is using `x = x` inside the inner function :)

Comment: @Sven: Initially, it was this, but I opted to make it look more like OP's code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Local variables are determined at compile time: the assignments to the variable `level` a few lines below the line the error occurs in make that variable local to the inner function.  So the line

```
if level is None:
```

actually tries to access a variable `level` in the innermost scope, but such a variable does not exist yet.  In Python 3.x, you can solve this problem by declaring

```
nonlocal level
```

at the beginning of the inner function, if you actually want to alter the variable of the outer function.  Otherwise, you can simply use a different variable name in the inner function.

Comment: Look, I do the same thing in the listing below that I posted. And it doesn't crash. I don't understand what is the difference.

Comment: @julkiewicz:  No, you don't do the same thing.  There are no *assignments* at all in your second snippet. (An assignment is a line like `a = 2`.  This line anywhere inside a function would make `a` a local variable anywhere inside this function.)

Comment: Oh, ok, so it detects the assignment. Stupid me. Thanks. I'll accept and add another edit. Thanks.